# Disable CSS in Wordpress Page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I hope you help me with something concerning wordpress and CSS. Wordpress applies CSS to all posts and pages. What I want to do is to disable a CSS style in specific object in the page.

Example:

When I add a table, the CSS is applied to the table. Now I want the table to have the basic HTML default style without CSS. Something like this:

```
<css do not apply here>
<table>
.
.
.
</table>
</css>
```

I have tried to change in the CSS buts it is so professional and huge.

How can I do that?

Comment: are you trying to edit a default theme or create a child theme?

Comment: <css do not apply here>
<table>
.
.
.
</table>
</css>

Comment: Have you tried using a css reset?

Comment: Is this a theme you purchased that now are trying to undo their CSS for just a certain element on the page?

Comment: you taking about the front end or the backend here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the page editor to html and add the style you want in the page in

```
<style></style>
```

tags, they will overide styles from a stylesheet. Or give a class to the table you want

```
 <table class="default">
     <thead class="default"></thead>
        <tbody class="default"></tbody>
          <tfoot class ="default"></tfoot>
  </table>
```

default css and put

```
table.default, .default tbody, .default tfoot, .default thead, .default tr, .default th, .default td{ style rule:property;}
```

that should do the trick

Comment: I forgot the closing / on the last able elem...... If I edit now it's a pain in the a**e